# How to deal with IPv6 in Wireshark?

Tags: macos, dns, network, wireshark

When I look up google, I get an IPv6 address and not an IPv4 address [image]

This is giving me issues in Wireshark with the source since I can’t manage to map the different addresses for the same name.

[image]

[image: I want it to look like this]

Can I force lookups to be IPv4 or do I have to handle more than one type of address to use wireshark?

Comment: I’m going to edit this. You are not seeing Mac addresses. You are seeing DNS provide you an IPv6 address for google. This may be an XY problem where you are asking about something unrelated that won’t even solve your actual problem...

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) dns servers that your Mac is getting from your router. Note that IPv6 dns can still return IPv4 addresses so you will need to handle both sets of addresses since some servers and networks are now IPv6 only.

IPv6 is a replacement for the older and more common IPv4 that you are used to seeing. Why? Because the world is *literally* running out of IPv4 IP addresses and the new IPv6 is an enormously larger address space (3.4×10^38 addresses).

There is *nothing wrong* with your Mac. You should leave it alone. Changing that to an IPv4 address, while possible, does nothing for you. And, in fact, it would be like someone deciding to go back to horse and buggy transportation instead of his car because he thinks horses are prettier. Certainly your call and certainly possible but not necessarily the most efficient use of your time and effort.

The conversion from IPv4 to IPv6 is taking longer than many people expected but it is happening and eventually the old IPv4 addresses will not be used. My advice to you, "get used to the new standard."

For some time, you might try disabling IPv6 entirely or force your Mac to use openly IPv4 based DNS services, but you will break things and be limited even today on what you can do by excluding the possibility of interacting with IPv6 networks.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are correct when they say nothing is wrong with using ipv6. If you are trying to learn or simplify things you can disable ipv6 in your network settings (which may affect connecting to your router depending on your isp.) to do this go to your network settings and change ipv6 from automatic.

[image: network settings]

Also,.. Wireshark allows you to choose an interface (WiFi and/Ethernet ect) to display the traffic from. That won’t be changing.. what you can do is customize the columns being displayed to only show ipv4 (resolved or unresolved) I.e. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) or 8.8.8.8... you would want to remove the ipv6 columns to avoid confusion. You can also define a single or range of IP addresses to display a customized name within wireshark. Check out editing wiresharks config files.